# Microsoft Bot builder : add pdf attachement and open it in web browser

Tags: .net, pdf, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to create a bot in which i need to add a pdf file as an attachement and when the user click on it it should be opened in a web broser or downloaded.
I've tried to do that but as you can see in  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aJWF.png) when i click on it nothing happens.

The code for adding the pdf attachement is :

```
  private static Attachment GetInlineAttachment()
            {
                var imagePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/mutuelle.pdf");

              //  var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));

                return new Attachment
                {
                    Name = "mutuelle.pdf",
                    ContentType = "application/pdf",
                    ContentUrl = imagePath
                };

            }
[LuisIntent("Mutuelle")]
        public async Task MutuelleIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {


            var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();
            try
            {

                Attachment attachment = GetInlineAttachment();
                replyMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { attachment };
                await context.PostAsync(" Vous retrouverez dans le document ci-dessous toutes les prestations prise en charge par notre mutuelle.");

                await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: What channel are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm currently using emulator but my goal is to make this work on Azure wich use (i think) Web chat channel

Answer (score 2):

> need to add a pdf file as an attachement and when the user click on it it should be opened in a web broser or downloaded.

It seems that you’d like to send the PDF file(s) that are stored in your application folder as attachment to user. If possible, you can try to store these PDF files in Azure Blob storage *(rather than in app folder)* that can be accessed from anywhere in the world via HTTP or HTTPS. Then you can send the file as attachment to user, like this:

```
var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();

replyMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
{
    new Attachment
    {
        Name = "mutuelle.pdf",
        ContentType = "application/pdf",
        ContentUrl = "https://{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/files/mutuelle.pdf?st=2018-05-04T08%3A03%3A29Z&se=2018-05-05T08%3A03%3A29Z&sp=rl&sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=sWYrbwPhgGeOEVNAAoRZXiIC%2B0sNtOMvokeRGkorDhM%3D"
    }
};

await context.PostAsync(" Vous retrouverez dans le document ci-dessous toutes les prestations prise en charge par notre mutuelle.");
await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
```

Besides, some channels may not allow bots to send certain types of file (such as .pdf) as attachment. In this scenario, if you store the file in Azure Blob storage, you can share the URL to that file as plain-text message to your user, then the user can copy that URL and open it in browser or download it. And if you want to restrict access to the file stored in Azure Blob storage, Azure Blob storage provides [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json) that can be used to grant limited access to storage resources.

**Note:** [issues are reported in github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+Unknown+attachment+type%2Cpdf) about some channels not support sending pdf attachment

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by using the following code, it looks like using a hero card really helps here.  Because at one point I know there was a bug in the emulator that if the bot shared a link it was unclickable because the click event registered on the chat bubble and not the link itself.  Not sure if that ever got fixed.

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
        var reply2 = await result as Activity;
        Activity reply = reply2.CreateReply();
        string image64;
        try
        {
            string base64String;
            var image = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(
                @"C:\Users\v-jassow\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Bot Application6\Bot Application6\nachos.pdf"));
            image64 = "data:application/pdf;base64," + image; 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Text = "Click me",
            Tap = new CardAction()
            {
                Value = @"http://localhost:3979/nachos.pdf",
                Type = "openUrl",
            }
        };

        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
        {
            heroCard.ToAttachment()
        };
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
}
```